# gridview row selection load page everytime

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Hi i am using gridview  control  to display data.On click of gridview  particular row i want to get that rows  id.

For this i have  used  this code:

```
 Protected Sub grdReport_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdReport.SelectedIndexChanged
             Dim row As GridViewRow = Me.grdReport.SelectedRow

        Dim InvoiceId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(grdReport.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
        Session("InvoiceId") = InvoiceId


 End Sub

Protected Sub grdReport_RowCreated(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdReport.RowCreated
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me.grdReport, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()))

        End If
    End Sub


Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    Dim gvr As GridViewRow
    For Each gvr In grdReport.Rows
        gvr.Attributes("onclick") = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(
                grdReport,
                String.Concat("Select$", gvr.RowIndex),
                True)
    Next

    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

Above code  is working fine for me  but whenever i click on gridview  row  then it loads  the  page again and page is getting slow.

please  let me know what i can do  so whole page not loads again and again on row click.

Answer (score 0):

first of all selectedindexchanged is not a good event if u want a reaction with a mouse onClick event.

selectedindexchanged is always executed for every row in the Grid when filling with Data

so if u have 100 rows the code gets executed 100 times before u see the grid

i would suggest using cellmousedown or cellmouseclick

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellMouseDown(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellMouseDown

    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left And e.RowIndex <> -1 And e.ColumnIndex <> -1 Then

Dim InvoiceId As Integer =  DataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("InvoiceId").value

End Sub
```

for your relaoding issues i guess it has to do with your render sub calling

imho its unneccessary for the simple task u want to acomplish